# XML/RSS within iPhone App... Is there any rules I must follow?

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, appstore-approval

I would like to feed data in to my app using plain old XML. Is this allowed, is their any restrictions on the feed at all? Does it need to be a valid RSS feed or the like, or can I use any XML I wish?

Thanks and Regards

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't specifically want to make an RSS reader application, any well-formed valid XML will do the trick. The NSXMLParser class can handle any valid XML. However, if you want to make an RSS reader app, the input needs to be valid RSS/Atom feed in order to conform to these standards - in this case, you can use an [RSS parser library](http://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit) in your app.